# Erratic scrolling behavior of Matlab editor window

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to enable proper scrolling of the editor window in Matlab? Any attempt to scroll (sliding my fingers on the touchpad) will cause it to veeery slowly jump a few lines and then speeds up suddenly but only cuts through multiple lines at a time rather than smoothly. The scrollbar doesn't move smoothly either.

I'm running Matlab R2015b on Mac OS 10.11.